# Импорт и экспорт в xml , json, yml

Tags: c#, json, xml, yml

Необходимо экспортировать и импортировать в три формата (xml , json, yml).
Как лучше это сделать? Помогите с примером и советом. Желательно не слишком мудрено, новичок в с#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, имеется класс:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Нам нужно сериализовать его экземпляр:

```
var person = new Person { Name = "Foo", Age = 33 };
```

Для xml можно использовать [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// Открываем пространство имён
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// Создаём сериализатор для нужного типа
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
// Выводим xml в поток/райтер (в данном случае, прямо в консоль)
xmlSerializer.Serialize(Console.Out, person);
```

Для json можно использовать библиотеку [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Думаю, комментарии не нужны.

Для сериализации в yaml используем библиотеку [SharpYaml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpYaml/) (её первую выдаёт поиск по nuget-пакетам).

```
using SharpYaml.Serialization;

var yamlSerializer = new Serializer();
var yaml = yamlSerializer.Serialize(person);
Console.WriteLine(yaml);
```

Десериализация происходит с точностью до наоборот. Полагаю, разобраться не составит труда.

Comment: Спасибо большое!